# anova - selecting multiple DVs simultaneously

Tags: r, anova

I am trying to run anova on many dependent variables. I have one independent variable, which is my grouping variable (Group). I have about 25 DVs - "TMTG, TMTF, CUE, CSE, TCUE, TCSE, WRS, WMAO, TWRS, TWMAO, JCP, JCPE ....etc". I used the following code for the first three variables and I am getting the desired output. How do I tweak the code to get the output for all 25 variables at the same time, but without naming them? I have another dataset with 100 DV - I cant write those out!

here is the data frame

```
    Group  TMTG  TMTF   CUE     CSE      WRS   
     TN      27    33    35.12   13.56    0
     TN      32    34    12.90   25.56    0
     TN      14    78    11      14.78    0
     TN      89    41    98      45.25    0
     TL      65    11    18.5    23.89    0
     TL      12    78    34.6    41.85    0
     TL      11    20    35.5    45.5     0
     TL      27    25    11.28   55.69    0
```

Here is the code:

```
    mydataframe
    manova_1 <-
    manova(cbind(TMTG, TMTF, CUE) ~ as.factor(Group), data = mydataframe)
    manova_1
    summary.aov(manova_1)
```

Here is the output

```
   Response TMTG :
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
   as.factor(Group)  1  0.535  0.5351  0.1683 0.6858
   Residuals        21 66.769  3.1795               

   Response TMTF :
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
   as.factor(Group)  1   0.02   0.016   5e-04 0.9831
   Residuals        21 749.13  35.673               

   Response CUE :
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
   as.factor(Group)  1   14.7   14.75  0.0372 0.8489
   Residuals        21 8325.7  396.46
```

I want to tweak this line:
        manova(cbind(TMTG, TMTF, CUE) ~ as.factor(Group), data = mydataframe, 
so that cbind can take in all the columns without me having to write them out. I tried cbind(2:24) but its not working! Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: I've posted an answer below, but just to double check, are you wanting to do a manova or a separate anova for each response variable? (Your code makes me think the former, but your question sounds like you might mean the latter).

Comment: @jruff003 Thanks! I do want a separate anova for each response variable. But I cant figure the code that will give me this all in one shot! Do you have any suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: @jruf003 Thanks for your help! Your answer helped. Also for the anova question in my previous comment - I figured it out..used the aov function. Thanks again..Upvoted your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 1) `Group` is the first variable in `mydataframe`, and 2) you want to do a manova as opposed to a number of separate anovas, you could replace the line:

```
manova(cbind(TMTG, TMTF, CUE) ~ as.factor(Group), data = mydataframe)
```

with:

```
manova(as.matrix(mydataframe[, -1]) ~ as.factor(Group), data = mydataframe)
```